# Windows Installer Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I change `DefaultLocation` value of the Application Folder (or Custom Folder) in code?

I can define `DefaultLocatio` as `[MY_DEFAULT]` on the File System in Visual Studio, add to `CustomActionData` `/myDefault=[MY_DEFAULT]` and pass `MY_DEFAULT` as parameter to the `msi` file.

In code I can read it as `Context.Parameters["myDefault"]`. This works.

But how can i change in code the value of the DefaultLocation where the application will be installed?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your Installer project, go to View->File System.

Now right-click on the '*Application Folder*' and select '*Properties Window*'. In the *Properties Window* you can edit the **DefaultLocation** field (see screenshot below).

[image]

By default, the **DefaultLocation** is *[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]* but you can change it to anything you like - **C:\MyApp\** or **[ProgramFilesFolder]MyApp\** or whatever.

Good Luck.